# Зависание браузера при добавлении цикла с проверкой в другой цикл

Tags: javascript

Есть функция:

```
function generator(gameBorad, boardSize, maxBombs) {
    let bombs = [];
    do {
        let x = getRandom();
        let y = getRandom();
        for (bomb in bombs) {
            if (!(bomb.x == x && bomb.y == y)) {
                bombs.push({
                    x: x,
                    y: y
                });
            }
        }
        
    } while (bombs.length < maxBombs);
    console.log(bombs)
}
```

При ее вызове браузер зависает.
Если удалить этот код:

```
 for (bomb in bombs) {
            if (!(bomb.x == x && bomb.y == y)) {
```

то она работает, почему этот код вызывает зависание?

Comment: В массиве 2 элемента, в for вы берете 1й элемент, добавляете 1 в конец массива, в условии for берете 2й элемен, но  там уже их 3, добавляете, в массиве уже 4, вы берет 3й, добавляете, в массиве 5 элементов, и так далее... вот вам и зацикливание, т.к. вы никогда не дойдете до конца массива, т.к. с каждой итерацией его увеличиваете

Answer (score 0):

Видимо `getRandom` даёт такой колоссальный разброс, что условие например никогда не срабатывает и в итоге `while` работает бесконечно. Понять это вы бы могли просто занявшись **[отладкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482)**

Comment: getRandom у меня ограничен от 0 до 5

Comment: Это вы так думаете.... Но это не важнл, т.к. абсолюнто вся суть написана в ответе. Можете включить отладчик и опсмотреть что происходит на каждой итерации, до условия или во время проеверки оного